# Every other window freezes after replacing mouse action - c#

Tags: c#, mouse

I'm writing an application that binds custom actions to my mouse buttons. For example, I connected the volume up to one of the thumb buttons. Everything works fine as long as I stay in one window because every other windows and the taskbar seems to freeze and it will take some time before the windows are activated again or if I kill my application or the window I am working in.

In the code below I capture the mouse events and check with the settings in the application if the button action is still default or if it has changed. If the action has changed, then the application should for example turn the volume up with two.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);

    public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static bool usingKeyboard = false;
    public static bool leftButtonDown = false;

    static int hMHook;

    public const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    //Declare MouseHookProcedure as a HookProc type.
    static HookProc MouseHookProcedure;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
        WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B,
        WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C,
        WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208,
        WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MouseHookStruct
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public int hwnd;
        public int wHitTestCode;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetLastError();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn,
    IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private int MouseHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        MouseHookStruct MyMouseHookStruct = (MouseHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseHookStruct));

        MouseUsageMessage message = new MouseUsageMessage(1);
        MouseUsageManager.mouseUsageMessageQueue.Add(message);
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                leftButtonDown = true;
            } else if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                leftButtonDown = false;                   
            } else if (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {

            } else if (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages) wParam) {

            } else if (MouseMessages.WM_XBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                switch (MyMouseHookStruct.hwnd)
                {
                    case 65536:
                        if (Settings.Default.thumbClick1User != Settings.Default.thumbClick1Default)
                        {
                            ExecuteAction(Settings.Default.thumbClick1User);
                            return 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 131072:
                        if (Settings.Default.thumbClick2User != Settings.Default.thumbClick2Default)
                        {
                            ExecuteAction(Settings.Default.thumbClick2User);
                            return 1;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } else if (MouseMessages.WM_MBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {

            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hMHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Why are the other windows freezing or why can't I use my mouse on the other windows after I've clicked the thumb buttons?

EDIT: Additional code

```
private void ExecuteAction(string setting)
    {
        VolumeControl vc = new VolumeControl();
        Keybindings kb = new Keybindings();
        switch (setting)
        {
            case "volUp":
                vc.VolUp();
                break;
            case "volDown":
                vc.VolDown();
                break;
            case "cut":
                kb.Cut();
                break;
            case "selectAll":
                kb.SelectAll();
                break;
            case "copy":
                kb.Copy();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The setting string that is sended to the ExecuteAction function is just a string with the action to be performed, i.e. copy, volume up, volume down etc.

VolumeControl class:

```
public class VolumeControl
{
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
    private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

    IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    public void VolDown()
    {
        SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
    }

    public void VolUp()
    {
        SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }
}
```

Create Hook function, the function that is called when the class is initialized:

```
    private void createHook()
    {
        while (hMHook == 0) //|| hKHook == 0)
        {

            //if (hMHook == 0)
            //{
                //hMHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                            //MouseHookProcedure,
                            //GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName),
                            //(IntPtr)0,
                            //0);
            //}

            if (hMHook == 0)
            {
                hMHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                        MouseHookProcedure,
                        GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName),
                        0);
            }

            if (hMHook == 0) //|| hKHook == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SetWindowsHookEx Failed");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hooked");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i could you help but i need to have all source code in relation with hook , like ExecuteAction, Settings, how you initialize the mouse hook and so on ... to understand

Comment: @Frenchy I've updated my question, please let me know if you need more

Comment: could you show the way you initialise the hook to obtain the mouse handle with SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: @Frenchy That's done in the create hook function. That function is called when the class is initialized.

Comment: when i use hook i have always hMHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                        MouseHookProcedure,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        0);

Comment: @Frenchy Just tried to do that, but get the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183246/discussion-between-frenchy-and-infiltrator).

Answer (score 0):

My solution, i have built a simple console project

when you launch program, the hook is activated, and you can toggle with middle mouse button. the right button up and letf button up play with system volume..

the main program:

```
using HookInput.API;
using HookInput.Mouse;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static MouseInput mouseInputHook = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vc = new  VolumeControl();
            mouseInputHook = new MouseInput(vc);
            mouseInputHook.setHook(true);
            Console.WriteLine("hook activated");
            Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());
        }
    }

    public class VolumeControl
    {
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

        public IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

        public void VolDown()
        {
            WindowsHookAPI.SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
        }

        public void VolUp()
        {
            WindowsHookAPI.SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
        }
    }
}
```

the APIs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HookInput.API
{
    public class WindowsHookAPI
    {
        //public delegate IntPtr HookDelegate(
        //    Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        public delegate IntPtr HookDelegate(Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, Int32 nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);


        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(Int32 idHook, HookDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hmod, Int32 dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    }
}
```

the hook and structures:

```
using HookInput.API;
using System;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ConsoleApp3;

namespace HookInput.Mouse
{
    public class MouseInput
    {
        private const Int32 WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

        private const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        private const Int32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        private const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
        private const Int32 WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
        private const Int32 WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
        private const Int32 WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206;
        private const Int32 WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;
        private const Int32 WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208;
        private const Int32 WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0209;

        private const Int32 WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

        private const Int32 WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B;
        private const Int32 WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C;
        private const Int32 WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x020D;

        private MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor;

        private bool hooked = false;

        private WindowsHookAPI.HookDelegate mouseDelegate;
        private IntPtr mouseHandle;


        private const Int32 WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private readonly VolumeControl vc;
        public MouseInput(VolumeControl vc)
        {
            this.vc = vc;
        }

        public void setHook(bool on)
        {
            if (hooked == on) return;
            if (on)
            {
                mouseDelegate = MouseHookDelegate;
                mouseHandle = WindowsHookAPI.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                if (mouseHandle != IntPtr.Zero) hooked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                WindowsHookAPI.UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHandle);
                hooked = false;
            }
        }

        private IntPtr MouseHookDelegate(Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            //mouseData:
            //If the message is WM_MOUSEWHEEL, the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta.The low-order word is reserved.
            //    A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user;
            //    a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. 
            //    One wheel click is defined as WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120.(0x78 or 0xFF88)
            //If the message is WM_XBUTTONDOWN, WM_XBUTTONUP, WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCXBUTTONUP, or WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK, 
            //    the high - order word specifies which X button was pressed or released, 
            //    and the low - order word is reserved.This value can be one or more of the following values.Otherwise, mouseData is not used.
            //XBUTTON1  = 0x0001 The first X button was pressed or released.
            //XBUTTON2  = 0x0002  The second X button was pressed or released.

            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT lparam = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            int command = (int)wParam;
            if (Code < 0 || command == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK || command == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
                return WindowsHookAPI.CallNextHookEx(mouseHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);

            else if (command == WM_XBUTTONDOWN || command == WM_XBUTTONUP)
            {
                int numbutton = ((int)lparam.mouseData >> 16) - 1;
                //return (IntPtr)1;
            }
            else if (command == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || command == WM_LBUTTONUP)
            {
                if (command == WM_LBUTTONUP)
                {
                    vc.VolDown();
                    Console.WriteLine("L down");
                }
            }
            else if (command == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || command == WM_RBUTTONUP)
            {
                if (command == WM_RBUTTONUP)
                {
                    vc.VolUp();
                    Console.WriteLine("L Up");
                }
            }
            else if (command == WM_MBUTTONDOWN || command == WM_MBUTTONUP)
            {
                if (hooked)
                {
                    setHook(false);
                    Console.WriteLine("hook deactivated");
                }
                else
                {
                    setHook(true);
                    Console.WriteLine("hook activated");
                }
            }
            else if (command == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
            {

            }

            return WindowsHookAPI.CallNextHookEx(mouseHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
        }


        ~MouseInput()
        {

        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will test this and get back if this works or not ASAP. Thanks anyways for providing an answer